# AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'shape' (Multi-Input Model)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, transfer-learning

I'm trying to implement transfer learning on a secondary model considering this layout, however, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

#### Transfer Learning Implementation

```
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('pretrained_model')

#Freeze all model layer weights
loaded_model.trainable = False

print(loaded_model.summary())

base_input1 = loaded_model.layers[0]
base_input2 = loaded_model.layers[1]
base_input3 = loaded_model.layers[2]

base_inputs = [base_input1, base_input2, base_input3]

base_output = loaded_model.layers[12]

output = Dense(1, activation = "relu")(base_output)
new_model = Model(inputs = base_inputs, outputs = output)

print(new_model.summary())
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could copy-paste the entire stack of error that your code produces, something that everyone should follow for error-related questions because that makes debugging that much easier.